# Factorial in C family languages

Tags: c#, c++

I've been trying to make a factorial function in C++, and I just found that inputs which are greater than 10 are not calculated correctly. I tried C# but I faced the same problem.

using this recursive function :

```
   int Factorial(int Number) {
        if (Number == 0) return 1;
        return Number * Factorial(Number - 1);
    }
```

The program returns 0 for large numbers, and even small inputs such 15 or 16 are wrongly calculated, I mean the result differs from what I get in windows calculator.

Comment: Integer overflows.

Comment: To make this slightly better try using `unsigned long long` as your type, which will handle much larger integers before overflowing.

Comment: I could guess that but what would be the best solution ?

Comment: I've used long before but for large values, it still returned 0

Comment: @Shaktal Not much, that takes you to 20! or 21! or so. One needs a big integer type to go far.

Comment: There is BigInteger in C# to deal with it.

Comment: Henk, do you really think your answer is appropriate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because factorials are big numbers and the don't fit in an `int` variable. It overflows.  If You use `unsigned long long` instead of `int`, You can compute greater factorials.

If the result doesn't need to be precise, You can use double as well. In the other case, You can implement the multiplication on arrays and You can compute as big factorials as You want.

In C/C++, I recommend the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/)

And because you asked for C family languages: Java has a `BigInteger` type which is also useful.

Comment: The long is still incapable of calculating 100! .

Comment: Since this is Windows, Unsigned long will only give another single bit.

Comment: That still doubles the max, though

Comment: I was just curios about the solution, so I'm not looking for any library since this not that important, I would like to know if there's any way to define such number which can hold unlimited digits. From my point of view I don't think that can be done.

Comment: @JohnJohn: I get overflows as low as 21! for `ulong`. Make sure you're running in a `checked` block.

Comment: @John John: You're aware that even an unsigned long (on most architectures) will only provide you with numbers between 0 and 4294967295.  100! is 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000

Comment: Yeah, the only way to calculate factorials of size 20 or higher is to use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

Comment: If you don't think it can be done, you're giving up too soon.  There is not a native numeric type that will represent 100!, but there are, for example, strings, which will.  How to make that "work" is where programming comes in to play.  If it's too much work, use a library.

Comment: There is nothing that is part of any C family language that supports really large numbers with "infinite precision". There is `double`, which will give an inprecise result (but good enough for figuring out, for example, the probability of winning the lottery or or some such - it doesn't really matter what the EXACT probability is, the first 15-16 digits is plenty enough). If you want to calculate pi with 100 decimal points, it's obviously NOT enough.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `int` is limited to 32 bits, and results of `10!` much beyond 10 will give you a bigger result. For larger values, you can get an approximate result using `double` as the result. If you want more than about 16 digits precision, you need to use a [multiprecision math library](http://gmplib.org/).

Using `uint64_t` would allow a larger number, but still fairly limited.

Answer (score 0):

Variables cannot hold an infinite number of values. On a 32-bit machine, the maximum value an `int` can represent is 2^31-1, or 2147483647. You can use another type, such as `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, or the largest one, `unsigned long long`. Factorials are big numbers, and can easily overflow! If you want arbitrary precision, you should use a bignum library, such as GNU GMP.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for You problem in simple.In C++ biggest in Long Long int. it has range of ~10^18. so you can't store numbers greater than that. and **100! have 158 digits in it so there is no way you can store that number in C++/C unless you can use vector/Array**

You are a new Programmer and you are using Only C++/C .

Then i will not recommend for using GMP library for programming purpose(**Algorithm or Programming contest Purpose**) unless you are programming for some software.

I think you can implement your own and use it.. I use this one for my own purpose in Programming contest and Algorithm problem.

```
// Shashank Jain
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#define LL long long int
using namespace std;
vector<int> fact;
void do_it(int num)
{
    int temp,carry;
    vector<int>:: iterator it;
    carry=0;
    for(it=fact.begin();it!=fact.end();it++)
    {
        temp=(*it)*num;
        temp+=carry;
        *it=temp%10;
        carry=temp/10;

    }
    if(carry!=0)
    {
        while(carry>0) 
        {       
            temp=carry%10;
            fact.push_back(temp);
            carry/=10;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{   
    int num,i,l;
    cin>>num; // enter number for which you want to get factorial
    fact.push_back(1);
    for(i=2;i<=num;i++)
        do_it(i);

    l=fact.size();  
    cout<<"The Length of factorial is: "<<l<<endl;
    for(i=l-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout<<fact[i];  
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Running Code link On Ideone](http://ideone.com/3OOhkJ)

This can easily get the factorial of 2000 in less than 1 sec. Or **else You can use GMP library. But Those are not allowed for Programming Contest like Google Code jam or Facebook Hacker Cup. or topcoder or anyother standard programming contest**