# Factorial showing wrong answer in main. Computed correctly in function

Tags: c++, overflow, long-integer, factorial

Please explain the reason for the following behavior. 
Correct answer is after debug "3". I want that to be replicated in main after "4".

```
long int fact[501]={0};

long int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n==0 || n==1)
            return 1;
    if(fact[n]>1)
            return fact[n];

    if((fact[n]=n*factorial(n-1))>=1000000007)
    {       cout<<"2"<<endl<<fact[n]<<endl;
            fact[n]=fact[n]%1000000007;
            cout<<"3"<<endl<<fact[n]<<endl;
    }return fact[n];
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    cout<<factorial(n)<<endl;
    cout<<"4"<<endl;
    printf("%ld\n",fact[n]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `printf()` in a C++ program? Best to stick with `std::cout`.

Comment: I thought there might be some limitation with std::cout output limit that would be creating an overflow.

Comment: What do you input as `n`?

Comment: @Scis I think that doesn't matter. `factorial(n)` does currently return `fact[n]`. So, both outputs must fit, with or without overflow.

Comment: @Scis 14. It is minimum where factorial crosses 10^9+7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factorial in C family languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136119/factorial-in-c-family-languages)

Answer (score 1):

The output from the line

```
        cout<<"3"<<endl<<fact[n]<<endl;
```

does not necessarily correspond to `n` from `main`.

Try this modified version to see the difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long int fact[501]={0};

long int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n==0 || n==1)
            return 1;
    if(fact[n]>1)
            return fact[n];

    if((fact[n]=n*factorial(n-1))>=1000000007)
    {       cout<<"2"<<endl<<fact[n]<<endl;
            fact[n]=fact[n]%1000000007;
            cout<<"3"<<endl<<n<<" "<<fact[n]<<endl;
    }return fact[n];
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    cout<<factorial(n)<<endl;
    cout<<"4"<<endl;
    printf("%ld\n",fact[n]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Try for n=14 and see the output for debug after 3 and debug after 4.

Comment: And I didn't understand why it wont take n from main, necessarily. Afaik, it takes the value in the innermost scope in case of same named variables. The outputted n value took it from main

Comment: `factorial` is a recursive function. The condition `(fact[n]=n*factorial(n-1))>=1000000007` is true when `n = 13` but not when `n = 14`. You get the output after "3" only for `n = 13`.

Comment: @RSahu: In fact, without 32 bits truncation, the condition is also true for `n == 14` ^_^ (https://ideone.com/gQrxyW)

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. When usig `unit64_t`, that seems to be true for all numbers after 13 until 30. Didn't test beyond 30.

Answer (score 0):

With your compiler/platform, you have `long int` with 4 bytes so your value is truncated

With `n >= 13`, we have

`fact[13] = 6227020800` which doesn't fit in a `uint32_t`

when truncated its new value goes to 1932053504 (and then `932053497` after modulo)

To fix your implementation you have to use `uint64_t`. (https://ideone.com/gQrxyW)