# Issue with my for loop

Tags: c++, loops

So I am making a factor recurring program for Uni and I haven't used for loops very often,

The idea is that you input a positive number and it does the calculation for you,
e.g. if the number 5 was chosen it would do the following:

1*2*3*4*5 = 120, it is working for most of my inputs but it doesn't get it right when I go pass 1

Just wondering if anyone knows what is wrong with my foor loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    int i, n, factorial = 1;

    cout<<"Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin>>n;
    if (n<=0) {

        cout << "Please enter a non-negative number!!!\n";
    }

    else {

    for (i = 1; i <=n; ++i) {
        factorial *= i;   // factorial = factorial * i;
    }

    cout<< "Factorial of "<<n<<" = "<<factorial;
    return 0;

    }
}
```

I am also planning so that when the number gets too big it goes into scientific notation, but I need to get this working first.

When I input 9 it does the calculation correctly:

```
1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9 = 362880
```

The way I have got it to be printed is:

```
Enter a non-negative integer:
9! = 362880
```

When I enter a number greater than 12, e.g. 13 I get

```
Enter a non-negative integer:
13! = 1932053504
```

The answer is wrong and also I need it to be:

```
Enter a non-negative integer:
13! = 6.22702e+09
```

Cheers.

Comment: `but it doesn't get it right when I go pass 1` Give some sample inputs, expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Your code work fine for Input 1 , factorial comes out to be 1.
What output you are looking for.

Comment: For this to be a correct factorial calculator, remember that `0! = 1`

Comment: I have just found out that i need to use long int for the variable but still stuck on the scientific notation bit.

Comment: It is happening because, for 13! the result value is more than max int can handle.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you mean by: `"when I go pass 1"`?

Comment: How on earth is this getting upvoted??? The first upvote was even before sample input and output had been added.

Comment: This question has heaps of duplicates and your problem has nothing to do with the for loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463794/factorial-overflow  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+factorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factorial in C family languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136119/factorial-in-c-family-languages)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this link to see each data type range (Min & Max values for type int):
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm
For scientific notation check this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/
Also check this link to understand the concept of overflow:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/

Answer (score 1):

It is because the output value for 13 exceeds the MAX value for a `signed int` (4 bytes) and causes integer overflow.

Consider changing `int` to `long long int` (8 bytes)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long long int i, n, factorial = 1;

    cout<<"Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin>>n;
    if (n<=0) {
        cout << "Please enter a non-negative number!!!\n";
    }

    else {

    for (i = 1; i <=n; ++i) {
        factorial *= i;   // factorial = factorial * i;
    }

    cout<< "Factorial of "<<n<<" = "<<factorial;
    return 0;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use long int and you will get correct values up to 20! or so.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`unsigned long long int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Input validation
int getNumber() {
    int n;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a non-negative number!\n";
        cin >> n;
    } while (cin && n < 0);
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int n = getNumber();
    unsigned long long factorial = 1;   // Maximum possible
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        factorial *= i;
    cout<< n << "! = " << factorial;
    return 0;
}
```

Input

> 13

Output

> 13! = 6227020800

See Ideone [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/bH1HXX).

**EDIT**: If you want scientific notation, use `long double` or stream format flags like [`std::scientific`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/). You can also set precision using `cout.precision method`.

Comment: thankyou so much, just one question, do you know how I can make the outuput in scientific notation, just the outpup so not the "13!" just the "6227020800" I wish to express it as "13! = 6.22702e+09" I want this to be only for the values greater or equal to 10, would i use an if statement